# How can i add admin profile at front end in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, profile, frontend

I am new in WordPress.
I have requirement for displaying admin profile in front end. Here Admin Profile means just admin's general information like Nick name, First Name,Last Name,Email,...
and i am not able to doing that with pinboard theme.
Any Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

please visit below every information there you can create it simply with this plugin

http://dulabs.com/frontend-edit-profile-for-wordpress/

or

http://www.cozmoslabs.com/1341-wordpress-profile-builder-a-front-end-user-registration-login-and-edit-profile-plugin/

Comment: thanks @Sonu Meena But i dont get my proper solution. Actually I want to display admin Profile in front end, and it is only in just read only as in view mode.